# Adding elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a new row to a table. Therefore I have tried it in two different ways. In my opinion both should work. But indeed the don't. The first approach does not work. But why?

First approach (not working...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Table</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addLine(nr, name, date) {
            var neueZeile = document.createElement("tr");
            var neuerEintrag1 = document.createElement("td");
            var neuerText1 = document.createTextNode(nr);
            var neuerEintrag2 = document.createElement("td");
            var neuerText2 = document.createTextNode(name);
            var neuerEintrag3 = document.createElement("td");
            var neuerText3 = document.createTextNode(date);
            neuerEintrag1.appendChild(neuerText1);
            neuerEintrag2.appendChild(neuerText2);
            neuerEintrag3.appendChild(neuerText3);
            neueZeile.appendChild(neuerEintrag1);
            neueZeile.appendChild(neuerEintrag2);
            neueZeile.appendChild(neuerEintrag3);

            var parentN = document.getElementById("myTable");
            parentN.appendChild(neueZeile);             
        </script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Website.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <td>Nr.</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Datum</td>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Max</td>
                <td>01.01.2001</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <form name=addRow>
            Nr.:
            <input type=text name=btn1>
                Name:
                <input type=text name=btn2>
                    Date:
                    <input type=text name=btn3>
                        <input type=button name=btn4 value=ADD
                            onclick="addLine(btn1.value,btn2.value,btn3.value)">
        </form>


        <input type=button name=btn5 value=DeleteLastAddedRow onclick="deleteRow()">


            <a class="back" href="Website.html">Zurück</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

My approach is not working. Does somebody know why or can help me?

Second approach (works fine...):

```
        function addLine(nr, name, date) {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow();
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell1.innerHTML = nr;
        cell2.innerHTML = name;
        cell3.innerHTML = date;
        }
```

I am really interested in why the the first approach is not working.
Does somebody have an idea?

Kind regards

Comment: Are you sure you GOOGLED enough before posting this question here? I am sure this is a very common requirement and there are tons of post showing how to do it. First link on google search - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Comment: did you enter any text in `btn1`, `btn2`, or `btn3` and then click `btn4`?

Comment: The first version adds cells (`<td>` elements) to the `<table>`. Despite the name of the function there's no row added.

Comment: Ah, the row was missing. But it still doesn't work. :( I have updated the code above...

Comment: [The second one works just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/jvdkvabd/). (You don't need those indexes in `insertCell`, but they're harmless.) Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: [And now you've changed what you've said is and isn't work, the first one works just fine too.](https://jsfiddle.net/50onoby8/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You missed to create `tr` element. Create `tr` and append it to `table` then all `td` to new `tr`.

Here is working code

```js
function addLine(nr, name, date) {
  var neuerEintrag1 = document.createElement("td");
  var neuerText1 = document.createTextNode(nr);
  var neuerEintrag2 = document.createElement("td");
  var neuerText2 = document.createTextNode(name);
  var neuerEintrag3 = document.createElement("td");
  var neuerText3 = document.createTextNode(date);
  neuerEintrag1.appendChild(neuerText1);
  neuerEintrag2.appendChild(neuerText2);
  neuerEintrag3.appendChild(neuerText3);

  var parentN = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  parentN.appendChild(row);
  row.appendChild(neuerEintrag1);
  row.appendChild(neuerEintrag2);
  row.appendChild(neuerEintrag3);
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <td>Nr.</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Datum</td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Max</td>
    <td>01.01.2001</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<form name=addRow>
  Nr.:
  <input type=text name=btn1> Name:
  <input type=text name=btn2> Date:
  <input type=text name=btn3>
  <input type=button name=btn4 value=ADD onclick="addLine(btn1.value,btn2.value,btn3.value)">
</form>
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers, and [since the OP's code works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119115/adding-elements-with-javascript#comment77209328_45119115), this question cannot be answered at present. Moreover, the question is why the second approach doesn't work. This is basically just the first approach copied into an answer.

Comment: You may have been looking at an out-of-date version of the question. The line `var neueZeile = document.createElement("tr");` is clearly in the first code example. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119115/adding-elements-with-javascript#comment77209261_45119115) suggests it may not always have been.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Yes, I answered older version of the question as second version is running fine. I only found mistake in first version, so added ans